# What to do when question asker doesn't appear to respond

Tags: discussion

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39376083/5115818). (Read comments below question). The problem is, I did it with vocation, in my spare time, trying to be as much clear as possible, but all I got back is complete nothing. Silence. I am not chasing rep, or anything else, but the guy just didn't even bother to make a comment like: "It doesn't work".

The question is what can we do about situations like this? I really don't want to invest my time into guys like this anymore.

Most likely it is duplicate, but I haven't find any - if you did please flag the question.

Comment: Aren't you being a bit impatient? It's only been 23 hours since you posted your answer...

Comment: Maybe (10 more to go...)

Comment: *"The question is what can we do about situations like this?"* First off, this is not even a day old. So give it some time. But second and probably more useful is to only write good answers with which you are satisfied by yourself with what you wrote and that you are happy just with the answer and ever response or upvotes is extra.

Comment: Don't expect to hear back quickly from anybody that starts his question with "I just start to learn" and you'll never be disappointed.

Comment: Just as people who answer do not care how urgent your question is the same goes with askers.  They are not under some time limit to respond if your answer worked for them or not.

Comment: To everybody that suggest I am impatient - please read the comments; the guy was pushing me, to make an answer as fast as possible. And suddenly he is silent? Common - you know he just don't give a shit. That is all.

Comment: Avoid help vampires like the plague.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Well, now you know. Next time someone tries to push you to answer their question as fast as possible, just ignore them and move on.

Comment: @Jerry as an aside, this is really a nice answer. Even if the OP doesn't come back to give you feedback, this is the kind of answers that will get you a long lasting stream of upvotes ;). Remember on Stack everything is always about the NEXT visitor, which you've definitely helped tremendously

Comment: @Patrice thanks. I hope vr got popular in time as I think it is future

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just as you are answering in your spare time, and under no financial or time obligation to do so, someone asking a question isn't forced to reply. They may be taking the time to verify your answer, might be called away due to other work, or otherwise unable or unwilling to vote or respond.

In fact, the purpose of Stack Overflow questions isn't just to solve a problem for a particular user, it's to provide general questions and answers that help many people. If you've written a good answer, odds are that more people than just the asker will benefit from it.

I've had many, many answers that I was proud of sit without votes or responses for years, only to have them accumulate votes over time as people came across the same issue. In fact, several of these answers even led to people tracking me down in person to thank me for them. *That's* the real measure of an answer's worth, not whether someone accepts it in under a day.